# POST wcf Service.svc calls fail even with explicit verbs allowed

Tags: wcf, iis-6

I have a .net CF proxy that issues a POST like so:

```
POST http://192.168.0.172:8080/MIS.WOService/Service.svc HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: http://tempuri.org/IWOService/LogIntoServer
Content-Length: 276
Connection: Keep-Alive
Expect: 100-continue
Host: 192.168.0.172:8080

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><LogIntoServer       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><emp_pin>55555</emp_pin></LogIntoServer></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

The calls always fail with the server returning:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Thu, 09 Dec 2010 16:07:14 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 0
```

However if, in fiddler I change the POST to a GET it works...

I have the configuration for the website to allow ALL verbs on the svc extension and the " verify file exist" is un-checked.

Does anyone know what could be causing this behavior by IIS 6 ?

When I inspect the IIS logs, it shows:

```
#Date: 2010-12-09 16:24:34
#Fields: date time s-sitename s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-    username c-ip cs(User-Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status 
2010-12-09 16:24:34 W3SVC1793831887 192.168.0.172 POST /MIS.WOService/Service.svc - 8080 - 192.168.200.67 - 404 0 0
2010-12-09 16:25:14 W3SVC1793831887 192.168.0.172 POST /MIS.WOService/Service.svc - 8080 - 192.168.200.67 - 404 0 0
2010-12-09 16:25:27 W3SVC1793831887 192.168.0.172 POST /MIS.WOService/Service.svc - 8080 - 192.168.200.67 - 404 0 0
2010-12-09 16:25:48 W3SVC1793831887 192.168.0.172 GET /MIS.WOService/Service.svc - 8080 - 192.168.200.67 - 200 0 0
2010-12-09 16:27:16 W3SVC1793831887 192.168.0.172 POST /MIS.WOService/Service.svc - 8080 - 192.168.200.67 - 404 0 0
```

Apparently I needed to put the name as url as such:

http://192.168.0.172:8080/MIS.WOService/Service.svc/basic

and then the server started allowing the svc to receive the soap messages...

Thanks
Greg

Comment: Can you provide how you defined your WCF service in code?

Answer (score 0):

I watched in fiddler what the wcfTestClient sent as requests...

http://192.168.0.172:8080/MIS.WOService/Service.svc/basic

and then the server started allowing the svc to receive the soap messages...